# Failed to Register WordPress Custom User Role via Ajax Submit Form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, forms

I edited my WordPress site custom registration page. I've added 2 new user roles:

1. Employer
2. Agent

I renamed default WordPress `Subscriber` role to `Job Seeker`. And, this `Job Seeker` role has all the default WordPress `Subscriber`'s capabilities.

Inside my Registration (`template-register.php`) page, I show an input field for the user that select Job Seeker as their role. This input field ID is `referralAgent`.

If they are `Job Seeker`, they will see this input field and need to enter Referral Agent username.

If they are `Agent` or `Employer`, this Referral Agent input field will be hidden to them.

I successfully added a `Job Seeker` user and record the user's Referral Agent data. But, when I try to register as an `Agent` or `Employer` user, it's failed. My submit button just loading for a while, nothing happened and all fields hold the entered values (they are not resetting themselves).

This is my code that related to the sign-up process inside my `functions.php` file:

```
function wpjobusRegisterForm() {

  if ( isset( $_POST['wpjobusRegister_nonce'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['wpjobusRegister_nonce'], 'wpjobusRegister_html' ) ) {

    $username = sanitize_text_field($_POST['userName']);
    $email = sanitize_email($_POST['userEmail']);
    $password = $_POST['userPassword'];
    $role = $_POST['userRole'];
    $ref = $_POST['referralAgent'];

    $registerSuccess = 1;
    $registerName = 1;
    $registerEmail = 1;

    if (username_exists($username)) {

      $registerSuccess = 0;
      $registerName = 0;

    } 

    if( email_exists( $email )) {

      $registerSuccess = 0;
      $registerEmail = 0;

    }

    // check if agent is in database or not
    if ( username_exists( $ref ) ){
        // agent exist
    }
    else {
        // agent is not exist
        $registerSuccess = 0;
        $registerRef = 0;
    }

    if($registerName == 0 AND $registerEmail == 0) {
        // email & username already exist
      $registerUserSuccess = 3;
    } elseif($registerEmail == 0) {
        // email already exist
      $registerUserSuccess = 2;
    } elseif($registerName == 0) {
        // username already exist
      $registerUserSuccess = 1;
    }
    elseif($registerRef == 0) {
        // agent already exist
      $registerUserSuccess = 6;
    }

    if($registerSuccess == 1) {
    // if no validation errors, save & register the user
    $user_id = wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email );

    // Set the role
    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
    $user->set_role( $role );

    // Set the referral agent data IF HAVE referral agent
    if ($role == 'subscriber') {
        add_user_meta( $user_id, 'referral_agent', $ref);
    }

    // Send email to user after they register
      $from = get_option('admin_email');
      $headers = "From: FindWorkers <".$from.">\r\n";
      $subject = "Registration successful";
      $msg = "Registration successful.\n\nYour login details\nUsername: $username\nPassword: $password\n\nYou can now login at: http://www.findworkers.my/login/ \n\nThanks.\n";
      wp_mail( $email, $subject, $msg, $headers );
      // end

      /*
      // Send email to admin when receive a registration request
      $to = get_option('admin_email'); // admin email
      $from = $email; // user email
      $headers = 'From: '.$from . "\r\n";
      $subject = "New User Registration";
      $msg = "New user registered on your site.\n\nThe user login details\nUsername: $username\n\nPlease login to Users area and approve or disapprove this user.\n\nThanks.\n";
      wp_mail( $to, $subject, $msg, $headers );
      // end
      */

      $login_data = array();
      $login_data['user_login'] = $username;
      $login_data['user_password'] = $password;
      wp_signon( $login_data, false );

      $registerUserSuccess = 4;

    }

  } else {

    $registerUserSuccess = 5;

  }

  echo $registerUserSuccess;

  die(); // this is required to return a proper result

}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_wpjobusRegisterForm', 'wpjobusRegisterForm' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_wpjobusRegisterForm', 'wpjobusRegisterForm' );
```

And this is my `template_register.php` file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template name: Register Page
 */

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 

    $profile = home_url()."/my-account";
    wp_redirect( $profile ); exit;

} 

$page = get_page($post->ID);
$current_page_id = $page->ID;

get_header(); ?>

    <section id="blog">

        <div class="container">

            <div class="resume-skills">

                <h1 class="resume-section-title"><i class="fa fa-check"></i><?php _e( 'Register an Account', 'agrg' ); ?></h1>
                <h3 class="resume-section-subtitle"><?php _e( 'You’ll be able to post your resume, apply for a job, add companies profiles and post job offers!', 'agrg' ); ?></h3>

                <div class="divider"></div>

                <div class="full">

                    <?php                   
                        if(get_option('users_can_register')) { //Check whether user registration is enabled by the administrator
                    ?>

                    <div class="one_half first">

                        <form id="wpjobus-register" type="post" action="" >  

                            <span class="one_half first">
                                <h3><?php _e( 'Username:', 'agrg' ); ?></h3>
                            </span>

                            <span class="one_half">
                                <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" value="" class="input-textarea" placeholder="" />
                                <label for="userName" class="error userNameError"></label>
                            </span>

                            <span class="one_half first">
                                <h3><?php _e( 'Email:', 'agrg' ); ?></h3>
                            </span>

                            <span class="one_half">
                                <input type="text" name="userEmail" id="userEmail" value="" class="input-textarea" placeholder="" />
                                <label for="userEmail" class="error userEmailError"></label>
                            </span>

                            <span class="one_half first">
                                <h3><?php _e( 'Role:', 'agrg' ); ?></h3>
                            </span>

                            <span class="one_half">
                                <select name="userRole" id="userRoleDropdown">
                                    <option>-- Select Role --</option>
                                    <option value="subscriber" id="jobSeekerOption">Job Seeker</option>
                                    <option value="agent">Agent</option>
                                    <option value="employer">Employer</option>
                                </select>
                                <label for="userRole" class="error userRoleError"></label>
                            </span>

                            <div id="referralAgentSection" style="display:none;">
                                <span class="one_half first">
                                    <h3><?php _e( 'Referral Agent (if any):', 'agrg' ); ?></h3>
                                </span>

                                <span class="one_half">
                                    <input type="text" name="referralAgent" id="referralAgent" value="" class="input-textarea" placeholder="" />
                                    <label for="referralAgent" class="error referralAgentError"></label>
                                </span>
                            </div>

                            <span class="one_half first">
                                <h3><?php _e( 'Password:', 'agrg' ); ?></h3>
                            </span>

                            <span class="one_half">
                                <input type="password" name="userPassword" id="userPassword" value="" class="input-textarea" placeholder="" />
                            </span>

                            <span class="one_half first">
                                <h3><?php _e( 'Repeat Password:', 'agrg' ); ?></h3>
                            </span>

                            <span class="one_half">
                                <input type="password" name="userConfirmPassword" id="userConfirmPassword" value="" class="input-textarea" placeholder="" />
                            </span>


                            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="wpjobusRegisterForm" />
                            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'wpjobusRegister_html', 'wpjobusRegister_nonce' ); ?>

                            <input style="margin-bottom: 0;" name="submit" type="submit" value="<?php _e( 'Register', 'agrg' ); ?>" class="input-submit">    

                            <span class="submit-loading"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"></i></span>

                        </form>

                        <div id="success">
                            <span>
                                <h3><?php _e( 'Registration successful.', 'agrg' ); ?></h3>
                            </span>
                        </div>

                        <div id="error">
                            <span>
                                <h3><?php _e( 'Something went wrong, try refreshing and submitting the form again.', 'agrg' ); ?></h3>
                            </span>
                        </div>



                        <script type="text/javascript">

                        jQuery(function($) {
                            $('#userRoleDropdown').change(function () {
                              var selectedId = $('option:selected', this).attr('id');

                              if (selectedId == "jobSeekerOption") {
                                // show the result box
                                $('#referralAgentSection').show("slow", "swing");
                              }
                              else{
                              // hide the result box
                                $('#referralAgentSection').hide("slow", "swing");   
                              }
                            });

                            jQuery('#wpjobus-register').validate({
                                rules: {
                                    userName: {
                                        required: true,
                                        minlength: 3
                                    },
                                    userEmail: {
                                        required: true,
                                        email: true
                                    },
                                    userPassword: {
                                        required: true,
                                        minlength: 6,
                                    },
                                    userConfirmPassword: {
                                        required: true,
                                        minlength: 6,
                                        equalTo: "#userPassword"
                                    },
                                    userRole: {
                                        required: true
                                    }
                                },
                                messages: {
                                    userName: {
                                        required: "<?php _e( 'Please provide a username', 'agrg' ); ?>",
                                        minlength: "<?php _e( 'Your username must be at least 3 characters long', 'agrg' ); ?>"
                                    },
                                    userEmail: {
                                        required: "<?php _e( 'Please provide an email address', 'agrg' ); ?>",
                                        email: "<?php _e( 'Please enter a valid email address', 'agrg' ); ?>"
                                    },
                                    userPassword: {
                                        required: "<?php _e( 'Please provide a password', 'agrg' ); ?>",
                                        minlength: "<?php _e( 'Your password must be at least 6 characters long', 'agrg' ); ?>"
                                    },
                                    userConfirmPassword: {
                                        required: "<?php _e( 'Please provide a password', 'agrg' ); ?>",
                                        minlength: "<?php _e( 'Your password must be at least 6 characters long', 'agrg' ); ?>",
                                        equalTo: "<?php _e( 'Please enter the same password as above', 'agrg' ); ?>"
                                    },
                                    userRole: {
                                        required: "<?php _e( 'Please select your role', 'agrg' ); ?>"
                                    }
                                },
                                submitHandler: function(form) {

                                    jQuery('#wpjobus-register .input-submit').css('display','none');
                                    jQuery('#wpjobus-register .submit-loading').css('display','block');
                                    jQuery(form).ajaxSubmit({
                                        type: "POST",
                                        data: jQuery(form).serialize(),
                                        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>', 
                                        success: function(data) {
                                            if(data == 1) {
                                                jQuery("#userName").addClass("error");
                                                jQuery(".userNameError").text("<?php _e( 'Username exists. Please try another one.', 'agrg' ); ?>");
                                                jQuery('.userNameError').css('display','block');

                                                jQuery('#wpjobus-register .input-submit').css('display','block');
                                                jQuery('#wpjobus-register .submit-loading').css('display','none');
                                            }

                                            if(data == 2) {
                                                jQuery("#userEmail").addClass("error");
                                                jQuery(".userEmailError").text("<?php _e( 'Email exists. Please try another one.', 'agrg' ); ?>");
                                                jQuery('.userEmailError').css('display','block');

                                                jQuery('#wpjobus-register .input-submit').css('display','block');
                                                jQuery('#wpjobus-register .submit-loading').css('display','none');
                                            }

                                            if(data == 3) {
                                                jQuery("#userName").addClass("error");
                                                jQuery(".userNameError").text("<?php _e( 'Username exists. Please try another one.', 'agrg' ); ?>");
                                                jQuery('.userNameError').css('display','block');

                                                jQuery("#userEmail").addClass("error");
                                                jQuery(".userEmailError").text("<?php _e( 'Email exists. Please try another one.', 'agrg' ); ?>");
                                                jQuery('.userEmailError').css('display','block');

                                                jQuery('#wpjobus-register .input-submit').css('display','block');
                                                jQuery('#wpjobus-register .submit-loading').css('display','none');
                                            }

                                            if(data == 4) {
                                                jQuery('#wpjobus-register :input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                                                jQuery('#wpjobus-register').fadeTo( "slow", 0, function() {
                                                    jQuery('#wpjobus-register').css('display','none');
                                                    jQuery(this).find(':input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                                                    jQuery(this).find('label').css('cursor','default');
                                                    jQuery('#success').fadeIn();

                                                    <?php $profile = home_url()."/my-account"; ?>
                                                    var delay = 1000;
                                                    setTimeout(function(){ window.location = '<?php echo $profile; ?>';}, delay); 
                                                });
                                            }

                                            if(data == 6) {
                                                jQuery("#referralAgent").addClass("error");
                                                jQuery(".referralAgentError").text("<?php _e( 'Agent is not exists. Please try another one.', 'agrg' ); ?>");
                                                jQuery('.referralAgentError').css('display','block');

                                                jQuery('#wpjobus-register .input-submit').css('display','block');
                                                jQuery('#wpjobus-register .submit-loading').css('display','none');
                                            }

                                            if(data == 5) {
                                                jQuery('#wpjobus-register').fadeTo( "slow", 0, function() {
                                                    jQuery('#error').fadeIn();
                                                });
                                            }
                                        },
                                        error: function(data) {
                                            jQuery('#wpjobus-register').fadeTo( "slow", 0, function() {
                                                jQuery('#error').fadeIn();
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                        });
                        </script>

                    </div>

                    <div class="one_half social-links">

                        <h3 style="margin-top: 0;"><?php _e( 'Social account register', 'agrg' ); ?></h3>

                        <?php
                        /**
                         * Detect plugin. For use on Front End only.
                         */
                        include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );

                        // check for plugin using plugin name
                        if ( is_plugin_active( "nextend-facebook-connect/nextend-facebook-connect.php" ) ) {
                          //plugin is activated

                        ?>

                        <a class="register-social-button-facebook" href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-login.php?loginFacebook=1" onclick="window.location = '<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-login.php?loginFacebook=1&redirect='+window.location.href; return false;"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i> Facebook</a>

                        <?php } ?>

                        <?php
                        /**
                         * Detect plugin. For use on Front End only.
                         */
                        include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );

                        // check for plugin using plugin name
                        if ( is_plugin_active( "nextend-twitter-connect/nextend-twitter-connect.php" ) ) {
                          //plugin is activated

                        ?>

                        <a class="register-social-button-twitter" href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-login.php?loginTwitter=1" onclick="window.location = '<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-login.php?loginTwitter=1&redirect='+window.location.href; return false;"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i> Twitter</a>

                        <?php } ?>

                        <?php
                        /**
                         * Detect plugin. For use on Front End only.
                         */
                        include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );

                        // check for plugin using plugin name
                        if ( is_plugin_active( "nextend-google-connect/nextend-google-connect.php" ) ) {
                          //plugin is activated

                        ?>

                        <a class="register-social-button-google" href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-login.php?loginGoogle=1" onclick="window.location = '<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>/wp-login.php?loginGoogle=1&redirect='+window.location.href; return false;"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square"></i> Google</a>

                        <?php } ?>

                    </div>

                    <?php }

                        else echo "<span class='registration-closed'>Registration is currently disabled. Please try again later.</span>";

                    ?>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**My questions**:

1. How to successfully register an user if they choose their role as an `Agent` or as an `Employer`?
2. How to send different sign-up email to different user role? Eg: if they are `Job Seeker`, send `email1`. If they are `Agent`, send `email2`. And if they are `Employer`, send `email3`.
3. How to set `referralAgent` field to `required` when a user choose the role as an `Job Seeker` and show an error message if it is `empty` using jQuery?